# Component Not Re-Rendering After Props Are Changed

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, highcharts, react-router

I'm passing a search input prop (searchTerm) to a React component (Graph).

It appears in dev tools that the Graph component is receiving the correct prop and state is being updated, but my fetch api function is not re-rendering the new data based on the updated prop.  If I manually force data to the API url, the fetch works, so I know it has to be a way i'm passing the searchTerm.  I've tried every iteration possible, but still can't get it to work.  Any ideas?

```
 class Graph extends Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
         this.state = {
            loaded: false,
            now: Math.floor(Date.now()/1000),
            data1: [],
            searchTerm: DEFAULT_QUERY
            }

    this.getData = this.getData.bind(this)
   }

   componentDidMount() {
       const {now, searchTerm} = this.state;
       this.getData(now, searchTerm);
}

   componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
       this.setState({searchTerm: nextProps.searchTerm });
    }

   componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
       const {now, searchTerm} = this.state;
       if(this.props.searchTerm !== prevProps.searchTerm) {
         this.getData(now, searchTerm);
    }
}




    getData = (now=this.state.now, searchTerm=this.state.searchTerm) => {
           let ticker = searchTerm.toUpperCase();
           console.log(searchTerm);
           fetch(`https://poloniex.com/public?
 command=returnChartData&currencyPair=USDT_${ticker}&end=${now}&period=14400&start=1410158341`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(results => {
         this.setState({
          data1:results.map(item => {
           let newDate = (item.date)*1000; //*1000
           return [newDate,item.close]
           })
        })
         console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.data1));
        })
        .then(()=> {
            const {data1} = this.state;
            this.setState({
              min: data1[0][0],
              max: data1[data1.length-1][0],
              loaded: true})
            })
      })
      }

    render() {
        const {data1, min, max} = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="graph">
        <HighchartsStockChart>
          <Chart zoomType="x" />

          <Title>Highstocks Example</Title>

          <Loading isLoading={!this.state.loaded}>Fetching data...</Loading>

          <Legend>
            <Legend.Title></Legend.Title>
          </Legend>

          <RangeSelector>
            <RangeSelector.Button count={1} type="day">1d</RangeSelector.Button>
            <RangeSelector.Button count={7} type="day">7d</RangeSelector.Button>
            <RangeSelector.Button count={1} type="month">1m</RangeSelector.Button>
            <RangeSelector.Button type="all">All</RangeSelector.Button>
            <RangeSelector.Input boxBorderColor="#7cb5ec" />
          </RangeSelector>

          <Tooltip />

          <XAxis min={min} max={max}>
            <XAxis.Title>Time</XAxis.Title>
          </XAxis>

          <YAxis id="price">
            <YAxis.Title>Price</YAxis.Title>
             {this.state.loaded &&<AreaSplineSeries id="price" name="Price" data={data1} />}
          </YAxis>


          <Navigator>
            <Navigator.Series seriesId="profit" />
          </Navigator>
        </HighchartsStockChart>

      </div>


     );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Cool, catches that don't do anything but hide potential problems in long chained promises. What could go wrong? No idea and nobody will every see it due to the `.catch(e => e)` chains...

Comment: good comment, actually on my list of things to accomplish once I can actually get the code to work :)   is this the preferred way to do it?  `.catch(err => {
      console.log('Error happened during fetching!', err);
    });`

Comment: If you don't have a concept for error handling, then you shouldn't handle them at all. Handle the ones you think that could happen (eg, if the request fails) as the next part of a potentially failing step. Your catch could then make sure that your component returns to a default state or sends the error message to its internal state. When an error occurs in your current code in step 1 (eg: fetch), it will ignore all other 5-6 then chains and jump to the catch block, and that was it, if you however handle catch directly after the fetch, you can chain more then statements behind it

Comment: okay thanks I appreciate that--i'm pretty new to coding and error handling is probably one of my weaknesses but those are helpful comments

Comment: Good, then remove those `catch` statements, and run your app again, check the debugger/console and see what went wrong

Comment: i turned off error catching and i now get a 'results.map is not a function' in my Graph component...but if i force a value in the fetch url for the getData function, the graph works fine. So it has to be how i'm passing the searchTerm to the getData function maybe?

Comment: Is there a reason you are only fetching `/tweets?ticker=$${searchTerm}` and not a full URL string (e.g. http://api.twitter.com/tweets/....)?

Comment: yeah twitter api doesn't allow you to hit their api on the front end, so I had to create a backend express route to fetch --thus that its route to the backend of my code

Comment: i added a componentWillReceive props lifecycle and set the state of the searchTerm so my state is now showing in the Graph component...but the data and graph are not updating...do i need to do something to update the rendering of the fetch api?

Comment: updated the question and code--i think probably a lot easier to understand now

Comment: and from where, you are calling fetch API when the state is updated/props received?

Comment: Well the component is referenced in my App component on render and is called like <Graph searchTerm=this.state.searchTerm>  And then as shown here, on load the getData method is called.  Does that help?

Comment: If the error is still that `results.map` is not a function then probably your `results` is not an array. Are you sure you are receiving a correct response and that `results` is an array?

Comment: Not getting any errors.  When the page first loads, the graph appears with the data from the DEFAULT_QUERY variable as shown above--works fine.  When I go to enter a value in the input box, no errors are generated. I can see from the console, that the data from the fetch api remains the same, but the props and the state are updating to the new value.  Normally--i would see the fetch api link the console, but not even seeing that when the input value is updated.

Comment: Well, were do you get your newest data from when your component receives new props? Currently no where, you are only loading on the initial mount, not when the props got updated

Comment: oh ok---guess that's the most confusing part about React for me...i thought that a component automatically re-rendered upon receiving a change in props---so i guess i have to call that fetchData call again...would that be in componentWillReceiveProps?

Comment: OK---i have updated my code- and made some sort of meaningful progress.   added the componentDidUpdate method and upon a new search input, the data is successfully being fetched.  Only problem is that the graph is not updating.  I included the render method for this component.  Not sure why it wouldn't update if i am setting state again on data1 variable for any new fetch.

Comment: You seem to call the `getData` method without parameters. I think that must be an oversight still, the default parameters will not change, I think that might be your last problem ;) Good work btw, you seem to learn by doing more and more. You can find more about the react lifecyle [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle)

Comment: Hmm--since the parameters reference the current state in the `getData` method, that would be okay i think right?  Especially since i'm setting state on `searchTerm` in `componentWillReceiveProps` (at least i think?)  I have a sneaking suspicion that the react-jsx-highcharts package i'm using does not have built in handling for updating data that is passed by reference--at least there's a blurb at the end of the NPM web page --https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-jsx-highcharts

Comment: No, that simply refers to the fact that react should never be by references, state must be different . Try passing the parameters

Comment: ok, i edited code above as to how i'm passing parameters--same issue, the fetch is working and getting the right data when props change, but graph is not re-rendering

Comment: How do you render the chart? Do you use `chart.update()` to update the chart? I can see you use wrapper for Highcharts, could you tell us which one?